# "System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException:HTTP could not register URL http://+:9999/

Tags: c#-4.0, httplistener

I am trying to start a service and getting an error.

```
System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: HTTP could not register URL http://+:9999/. Another application has already registered this URL with HTTP.SYS. ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Failed to listen on prefix 'http://+:9999/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine.
   at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.EndOpen(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.Http.SelfHost.HttpSelfHostServer.OpenListenerComplete(IAsyncResult result)
```

Comment: It pretty much says there in the error message: another program is already using that port. Maybe even the same program, if you started it earlier. Either use a different port or stop that other program.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have some service already running at port 9999.

You can go to resource monitor and network tab.
Inside TCP Connections section, check the local port column to check which service is already using this port.

Hope this helps.

Comment: None of the services is using the port.I have used these 2 commands to register the URL netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:9999/ user=kronosint\devpair
--netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:9999/ user=domain\user
Make sure the user is the useraccount that will run the service.

- Run this command to register server certificate on  the listening port:
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:9999 certhash=thumbprint appid={some id}